# Entity Framework's TPC mapping results in error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have these models:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    public int Payment { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher : Person
{
    public int Wage { get; set; }
}
```

And in database, I have two tables called `Teachers` and `Students`. I want to use Entity Framework's TPC mapping. My context class is:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .Property(i => i.PersonId)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Teacher", "dbo");
        }); 

        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Student", "dbo");
        }); 
    }
```

But when I want to add a teacher, I get this error:

> The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.

What's wrong here?

Comment: I know but i can't say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx):

> The reason we got this exception is because DbContext.SaveChanges()
> internally invokes SaveChanges method of its internal ObjectContext.
> ObjectContext's SaveChanges method on its turn by default calls
> AcceptAllChanges after it has performed the database modifications.
>
> AcceptAllChanges method merely iterates over all entries in
> ObjectStateManager and invokes AcceptChanges on each of them. Since
> the entities are in Added state, AcceptChanges method replaces their
> temporary EntityKey with a regular EntityKey based on the primary key
> values (i.e. PersonId ) that come back from the database and
> that's where the problem occurs since both the entities have been
> assigned the same value for their primary key by the database (i.e. on
> both PersonId = 1) and the problem is that ObjectStateManager
> cannot track objects of the same type  with the
> same EntityKey value hence it throws. If you take a closer look at the
> TPC's SQL schema above, you'll see why the database generated the same
> values for the primary keys: the PersonId column in both
> Student and Teacher table has been marked as identity.

Try this:

```
public srting PersonId { get; set; }
```

and change your config to:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .Property(i => i.PersonId)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

and change you class to `abstract`/

Comment: so, there is no way to use DatabaseGeneratedOption,Identity when we use TPC, right?